# "c.lang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument" when running gfortran on Mac

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile a "hello world" text file, but keep receiving an error in my mac terminal:

```
    (base) name@Names-MacBook-Pro-3 File % gfortran -o test.exe try.f90
    c.lang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-x86-pad-for- 
    align=false'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) --help'.
```

My fortran version:

```
   GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 11.3.0_1) 11.3.0
```

text file (try.f90) that I wrote in VS:

```
    program try

     print*,'hello world!'

    end program try
```

I tried with a space and without a space before print. The code I am using is from a youtuber who uses Atom text editor and the video is from 2020.

I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: How did you install gfortran? Which version? What does `gfortran -v` print?

Comment: I installed gfortran using "brew install gcc" which I suspect comes from https://gcc.gnu.org/. The command outputs: gcc version 11.3.0 (Homebrew GCC 11.3.0_1)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and it seems the root cause was `Xcode` vs `Command Line Tools` were used. Probably some inconsistency (e.g. I might have upgraded the cli but not the gui).

Anyway, before

```
$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

I fixed this with

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and then `gcc-12` or `gfortran` from `homebrew` worked as expected.

FWIW

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
$ gcc-12 --version
gcc-12 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Thanks! I had an issue with gcc-12, "fatal error: "_stdio.h" No such file or directory", and the `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` step was key to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by updating Xcode. There was an incompatibility between gfortran and clang. To see available updates:

```
softwareupdate --list see the list of outdated software.
softwareupdate --install <name>
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily show up out-of-date Xcode Command Line Tools. I had to do `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools; sudo xcode-select --install` to force, as advised by `brew upgrade`.

Comment: Plus one for a comment above. It will help me with the same issue